# How to prevent re-rendering using lazyLoad in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I went through an interview in which interviewer asked me
**"ways to prevent re-rendering of component in react using lazyload"**
I was not able to answer.

Can anyone help me with that question?

Comment: Did you check react's official guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html? Also, lazy loading and re-rendering are two very distinct concepts that don't have anything in common.

Comment: Both are different topics.

Comment: Oh okay. Thats why m not getting anything from google.....So lazy loading means rendering pages on user request and...preventing re-rendering means avoiding component to load on each request and that we can achieved by react hooks-useMemo() and useCallback()............ **please correct me if m wrong**

Comment: You are absolutely right